# Compact subset of a measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, compactness

Let S contained in R^n, be a measurable set with μ(S) < ∞, and let ε > 0 and also $$\epsilon<\mu(S)$$be a positive real number. Show that there exists a compact subset K contained in  S such that μ(K)- ε<μ(S). Where a set E is measurable if $$E\subseteq R^{n}$$
  is measurable if, for every $$S\subseteq R^{n}$$

$$
\mu^{*}\left(S\right)=\mu^{*}\left(S\cap E\right)+\mu^{*}\left(S\cap E^{c}\right)
  $$

Comment: I had to struggle with "epsilon below the one of S"! Do you mean "its measure is $\mu(S)-\epsilon$"? If so, you also need that $\epsilon \le \mu(S)$.

Comment: Sorry TonyK. Let me know if it is more comprehensible now. :(I am fairly new and I am trying to understand how can i copy Latex in here directly. Apologies again for any inconvenience.

Comment: No, it's still not right. If $K$ is contained in $S$, then $\mu(K) \le \mu(S)$, so $\mu(K) - \epsilon \le \mu(S)$ automatically. I think you had better give it to us word for word.

Comment: Ok I get it there was a truly conceptual problem in my question, not just a typo. Thank you TonyK!!

Comment: Is it now correct? I copied literally from the text so there should be nothing more I could add.

Comment: How do you define a measurable set? The answer would depend on that.

Comment: Ok I updated also with that..

Comment: No, it's _still_ not right. You can just let $K$ be the empty set! Are you translating this from a foreign language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prove this in three steps :

1. If $S$ is a measurable set, then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is an open set $O$ such that $S\subset O$ and $\mu(O\setminus S) < \epsilon$

Proof :

Given $\epsilon > 0$, choose a countable collection of rectangles $I_n$ such that
$$
S \subset \cup I_n
$$
and $\sum v(I_n) < \mu(S) + \epsilon$. Now take $O = \cup I_n$.

1. If $S$ is a measurable set, then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a closed set $F \subset S$ such that $\mu(S\setminus F) < \epsilon$ (Just apply (1) to $S^c$ and then take complements)
2. Choose a closed set $F$ as in (2), and take the compact sets
   $$
   K_n = F\cap \overline{B(0,n)}
   $$
   Since $\mu(S) < \infty$, it follows that
   $$
   \mu(S\setminus F) = \lim \mu(S\setminus K_n)
   $$
   Now choose $n$ large enough.

Comment: Thank you so much Prahlad!!This is so helpful!! Thank you very much for all your help.